Solving truth liar random puzzles without self refernce questions

You’re a logician who wants to know which of two roads leads to a village. Standing nearby, inevitably, are three natives: one always lies, one always tells the truth, and one answers randomly. You don’t know which is which, and you can ask only two yes-or-no questions, each directed to a single native. How can you get the information you need?

A standard way to solve these questions is to either ask the self referential question of the form, "If I were to ask you this then would you say yes?" or to ask, "Is X more likely than Y to tell the truth?”
But, I don't want to use either of the above question formats. Is it still possible to solve this question?
The original question is from mathematical physicists Vladas Sidoravicius and Senya Shlosman, via Dartmouth mathematician Peter Winkler’s “Seven Puzzles You Think You Must Not Have Heard Correctly”

You don't need to use those exact phrasings, but you'll need to use questions equivalent to, or the exact opposite of, those questions.

You can't get any information about the path from the random person.  You must ask at least one question of the truther or the liar (call these "useful" people).
You can't ask the same person both questions (that person might be the random).
You must identify at least one person questioned as useful, and be able to decide which path to take based on that person's answer.  (Handwave - if you aren't certain, it's possible for fate to give answers such that if the first person was random, you should take path 1, and if the second was random, you should take path 2)
You must identify a useful person on the basis of the first answer, and ask that person your second question.

Call the person you ask the first question "A"; the person you ask the second question when the first answer is "yes" "B", and the person you ask the second question when the first answer is "no" "C".
So, to find that question, use Wei-Hwa's method:

Construct a truth table with a row for each possible set of truthiness for the askees
Add a column "Answer received" which contains the answer you want to get in that case (or "?" if you don't care).
Add a column "True Answer" that is identical to the previous column when the person asked is truthful, and its opposite when the person asked lies (or "?" if previous was "?".
Construct a question whose correct answer is "yes" for every state with a "yes" in the last column, and whose correct answer is "no" for every state with a "no" in the last column.

spacing
A B C Recv True
T F R Y    Y
T R F N    N
R T F ?    ?
R F T ?    ?
F T R Y    N
F R T N    Y

A question with these properties is "Is either B the one who always lies, or C the one who is always truthful?"
For your second question, the state is whether the person asked is T or F, and whether path L or R is correct:
WLOG, take the left path if s/he says "yes" and right if s/he says "no":
Askee Path Recv Corr
T     L    Yes  Yes
T     R    No   No
F     L    Yes  No
F     R    No   Yes

A question which has this property is "Are you the truthful person and the left path leads to the village, or you the liar and the right path leads to the village?"
But whatever question you devise will need to have the exact same or exact opposite truth table, so will be equivalent or opposite.
